# Find and replace multiple URLs in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

What I want to do is be able to find instances of YouTube URLs in an NSString (there are often at least 2-3 in each post) and change them to proper YouTube embeds.

The posts that I am downloading are from Wordpress and the site has support for automatically resolving YouTube links for embeds, so when I get them and place them in an NSString they only include the URL which I need to change to show in a WebView.

What would be the best way to achieve essentially wrapping all the existing URLs in YouTube embed code? I honestly can't think up any remotely compact code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might search for a regular expression which scans a URL. Having that, you can apply the regex with `NSRegularExpression`.

Comment: post you code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can parse URL content with hpple. How to work with it you can learn [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios). After parse you can check does link contains "youtube" or something else what do you need. I hope it will help you.

Comment: It's from a JSON feed so I'm not looking to parse a URL, just get a URL and change it from an NSString.